# App Doesn't Load When Controller is in Separate File

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-controller

This is an addition to my question: [AngularJS Doesn't Resolve An Array of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413038/angularjs-doesnt-resolve-an-array-of-objects)

As I've stated in my final edit:

> I have resolved this by placing controller in the same file where app
>   is defined - `app.js`. When placed in separate folder it is not working.
>   I do not know why at this point.

but why is this? I've tried several times and app doesn't load when the controller is in separate file - `js/controller.js`. And I have checked the path, it is correct.

Here is the app:

This is my HTML:

```
<body data-ng-app="App">
*
*
*

<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
     <p>{{obj.desc}}</p>
</div>

*
*
*
</body>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);
```

controller.js

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.obj = [
          {
                intro: "intromessage",
                desc: "desc"
          },
          {
                intro: "intromessage2",
                desc: "desc"
          }
       ];
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming controller.js is loaded correctly. You need to define the `var app` in your new file:

```
var app = angular.module('App'); //Continue your app module
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.obj = [
          {
                intro: "intromessage",
                desc: "desc"
          },
          {
                intro: "intromessage2",
                desc: "desc"
          }
       ];
   });
```

Comment: actually its not required

Comment: if he is operating in a different scope it is

Comment: @dbarthel what do you mean by different scope?

Comment: Well, believe it or not, it worked! Please explain more @dbarthel. Thanks. As in one of my previous apps this only bugged the controller. What do you mean 'a different scope'?

Comment: it is not required if he is operating on the global scope (global vars), which he obviously is after his response.
Usually it is good practice to not operate in the global scope and wrap your angular code into function calls to separate them. Then each file has its own scope and you need to define your module new

Comment: please read on about var scopes here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp
Its not that complicated but there are better sources to understand than a short comment here ;)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

you can solve this easily . You have to do small modification in your js files.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);
app.controller('Ctrl',homeController);
```

controller.js

```
var homeController = function($scope) {
$scope.obj = [
      {
            intro: "intromessage",
            desc: "desc"
      },
      {
            intro: "intromessage2",
            desc: "desc"
      }
   ];
   }
```

This will work for you. Make sure that in your layout page you include controller js before app js

Example:

```
<script src="~\controller.js"></script> <!--first-->
<script src="~\App.js"></script> <!--second-->
```

Comment: This is also good! Sometimes you have to go like this, sometimes you don't. Can you please explain?

Comment: Its all related to scope of variable. If you define

Comment: Sorry for incomplete comment, its all about scope. if u define **app** variable in app.js and call it in **controller** , the app variable is undefined till then. So it will not register. If you want to make your original code itself to work, the in layout inclue **app.js** first than **Controller** even that will work :) try once

Comment: Thanks mate, more clear now. Angular is really something special. :)

Comment: Welcome tholo :) Yes,it is :)